# Pug Allergy - Skin Rash

Tags: dogs, health, medicines, skin-condition, allergies

I have a pug and it's usually very active and we don't feed anything apart from Drools Focus Puppy.

Recently, it got a Skin Rash[image: Skin Rash] on the top neck region and gradually it started expanding. We had taken him to doctor for 3 times already and every time we visit, he gives an injection but the skin rash doesn't go off.

we started worrying about it and thought of asking here as I'm losing trust in my vet because the rash has been there for more than 2 months.

Recently, my Vet has given an ointment[image: Pic] and asked to apply twice a day and I haven't seen any change in that and I feel like it's growing.

Note: Bath - once a week

Comment: Is it normally that blueish color? Or is that the ointment?

Comment: actually, it's not blueish. the pic reflection might be a problem, but it is a little white in color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem with my pug.

We took him to several vets.

What we do to reduce this skin problem is using a 2% ketoconazole ointiment everyday.

Have to clean the apartment floor every day because he lives inside the apartment with us (we use products to clean the house that are proper to pets to avoid alergies).

We use a proper dog shampoo or dermatological one because if you use any different one it will increase the skin problems. Normally the shampoo has a neutro pH. During summer we wash him once a week.

Don't use cold water while bathing him. Regular water temperature or a little bit warm.

Clean his bed everyday.

Brush him everyday.

Clean his eyes, nose and ears with proper dog medicine.

Don't go out with him because he can get fleas or ticks from other dogs.

Use Elizabethan colar while he is in treatment.

That procedures will reduce a lot this problem.